# Blank response when using the PING command

Tags: networking, ping

I was running the PING command to a mikrotik hAP lite router from power-shell to determine the consistent connectivity before running a trouble shooting application. It was working well before at some point mid operation the command froze. I quit the command and tried to restart, but it wasn't giving any response.  I was running the command through the Ethernet adapter.

I disconnected it and tried to run a different ping to Google's public DNS server, `8.8.8.8` but still no response. I also tried to ping the loop-back address, `127.0.0.1`, but no response.

Was as so: [image]

Has anyone come across such a scenario, and how did you go about solving the issue ?

The machine being used to ping and the router are in the same subnet.

I have rebooted the devices multiple times.

Comment: Have you rebooted the router?

Comment: Or rebooted the PC itself. I have seen the Windows TCPIP stack getting really messed up before for no apparent reason, which got only be reset by a FULL reboot (not the quick semi-reboot that Windows now prefers to do).

Comment: I took shut down the machine, went to hang out with some friends, came back hours later and still the same issue persisted.

Comment: Don't shutdown, **reboot**. Shutdown does not do the same as a reboot, in a shutdown your core OS just hibernates and problems like this will persist. Reboot actually loads the OS from scratch.

Comment: @Mokubai this has worked. Nice. Thank you. Would you know what causes such behavior?

Comment: Drivers, misbehaving programs, programs allocating but never freeing things, resource exhaustion, misconfigurations that happen over time... lots of things can cause it. Rebooting just allows things to start up cleanly without all the baggage of previous programs having broken things. The old question of "Have you tried turning it off and back on" should now be "Have you rebooted? No, I don't mean shutdown." [Fast startup](https://www.howtogeek.com/243901/the-pros-and-cons-of-windows-10s-fast-startup-mode/)

Comment: @Mokubai thank you for the response. Will consider this exact move in other scenarios that may seem trivial.

Answer (score 0):

> Don't shutdown, reboot. Shutdown does not do the same as a reboot, in a shutdown your core OS just hibernates and problems like this will persist. Reboot actually loads the OS from scratch.

Just wanted to highlight that this worked for me, as things have resumed back to the previous state.